# How do I merge based on a missing elements with JQ?

Tags: bash, jq

I have two JSON files that I am working with: dest_sr.json and src_templates.json

What I would like to is create a new JSON object that combines keys from JSON object #1 (specifically the Template_SR key) and JSON object #2 (the Template_Name and Template_ID keys), but only when a VM-Template cannot be found on Pool_ID that matches on both object #1 and object #2

For the two given JSON objects:
dest_sr.json:

```
{
  "Type": "pool",
  "Pool_ID": "adb58e84",
  "Template_SR": "fc820294"
}
{
  "Type": "pool",
  "Pool_ID": "d2dea684",
  "Template_SR": "313f2a07"
}
```

src_templates.json:

```
{
  "Type": "VM-template",
  "Template_Name": "CentOS 7 CloudInit V1",
  "Template_ID": "9b1833a3",
  "Pool_ID": "adb58e84"
}
```

I would like to create a new JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "Template_ID",:"9b1833a3",
  "Template_SR":"313f2a07",
  "Template_Name":"CentOS 7 CloudInit V1",
}
```

Using Stackoverflow I was able to hack together a hashJoin from examples that looks like this, where it performs a hashJoin on the .Pool_ID attribute to create a new object:

```
# hashJoin(a1; a2; field) expects a1 and a2 to be arrays of JSON objects
# and that for each of the objects, the field value is a string.
# A relational join is performed on "field".

def hashJoin(a1; a2; field):
  # hash phase:
  (reduce a1[] as $o ({};  . + { ($o | field): $o } )) as $h1
  | (reduce a2[] as $o ({};  . + { ($o | field): $o } )) as $h2
  # join phase:
  | reduce ($h1|keys[]) as $key
      ([]; if $h2|has($key) then . + [ $h1[$key] + $h2[$key] ] else . end) ;

hashJoin( $file1; $file2; .Pool_ID)[]
```

When I call JQ to perform the hashJoin, I get a new object that looks like this:

```
/tmp $ jq -nc --slurpfile file1 /tmp/dest_sr.json --slurpfile file2 /tmp/src_templates.json -f hashJoinSimple.jq

{
  "Type":"VM-template",
  "Pool_ID":"adb58e84",
  "Template_SR":"fc820294",
  "Template_Name":"CentOS 7 CloudInit V1",
  "Template_ID":"9b1833a3"
}
```

Is there any way I can write my merge so that the object would look like this?

```
{
  "Type":"VM-template",
  "Pool_ID":"d2dea684",
  "Template_SR":"fc820294",
  "Template_Name":"CentOS 7 CloudInit V1",
  "Template_ID":"9b1833a3"
}
```

Comment: The requirements (in the para beginning "What I would like to do") are incomplete and somewhat confusing.  Please clarify.  Please also consider following the [mcve] guidelines more closely - e.g. you could give much shorter values for the ids.

Comment: Clarified the "What I would like to do" section (hopefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think given your particular inputs and your desired result, I don't think the hashing is necessary. It seems like all you need to do is select the inputs from `dest_sr.json` where it doesn't match the id in `src_templates.json`, then combine it with the desired values from the template.

```
$ jq --argfile template src_templates.json '
select(.Pool_ID != $template.Pool_ID) + ($template|{Template_Name,Template_ID})
' dest_sr.json
```

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to be a bit more straightforward than dealing with a hash merge!

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since it is answering the question I had asked :) Thanks!